# Highcharts and Extjs 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts, extjs4, highcharts

I need to use Highcharts within ExtJs 4 and I'm really stuck. I tried adapters that I found, but they are for highstock. Has anyone experience with highcharts and extjs 4?
Any help would be most welcome.
Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 0):

The adapters delivered with Highcharts/Highstock are used to even out the differences between various javascript frameworks, how they handle animations and events etc.

Highcharts comes with **jQuery** support built-in.
Sites using **MooTools** need to include `mootools-adapter.js`
Sites using **PrototypeJS** need to  include `prototype-adapter.js`